# How to add the correct repositary in gedit?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, gedit

I am trying to install Rstudio in my linux mint 17.1 using software package manager.

I tried the following way which is given by [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197564/how-do-i-add-a-line-to-my-etc-apt-sources-list). But I am getting the following error.

> E: Malformed line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist)
>
> E: The list of sources could not be read.

My Screen shot is here..
[image]

I need to add the correct repository in the gedit for the latest version of R(full software with packages or libraries)..

Comment: I'm not sure that apt-get is able to read a .git repo.

Comment: how we can check that???@purplepsycho

Comment: don't post screenshots. they're unreadable.  cat the text files and copy-paste the text.  that's readable on any screen, at the viewer's preferred font size.

Answer (score 2):

apt is a tool to install software from *apt-get* repositories. I think that you confuse (mix up?) different kinds of repo (because git works also with repo, but it's another subject).

First, you will have to fix your sources.list file, ie remove the .git line you added.

After that, you may follow this tutorial: http://www.thertrader.com/2014/09/22/installing-rrstudio-on-ubuntu-14-04/ that describes what i think you want to do.

Comment: david@david-Lenovo-B460e ~ $ sudo apt-key adv –keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com –recv-keys E084DAB9
[sudo] password for david: 
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.U9IVJfYH5F --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg –keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com –recv-keys E084DAB9
usage: gpg [options] [filename]
david@david-Lenovo-B460e ~ $ sudo add-apt-repository ‘deb http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/’

Comment: with the help of the link you have given, I did the above and its giving these messages..@purplepsycho

Comment: I dont know whether this is working propertly or not..